# Can the Foundry Object View Markdown widget open links in a new tab?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-object-views

Is it possible to configure links defined in the Object View Markdown widget to open in a new tab by default (rather than making people cmd+click)?

Answer (score 1):

By default, links to external websites in the Object View Markdown widget will open in a new tab and links to Foundry will open in the same tab. This behaviour can currently not be controlled from the widget settings. However, you can do this directly in Markdown.

So Markdown's link syntax doesn't support `target="_blank"`, but you can use plain HTML in Markdown. This means that you can do `<a href="http://example.com/" target="_blank">Hello, world!</a>` to force a link to open up in a new tab.